# Text not aligning in the center and not changing size

Tags: html, css

So my font is not changing size or being center aligned. I've tried heaps of stuff but without results. I'd like the code (text) centered, but it currently is being aligned to the left. I'd also like the text to be a lot bigger. Please have a look at my code!

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

...

<div class="qt">
    <?
        $filename = "quotes.txt";
        function RandomLine($filename) { 
            $lines = file($filename); 
            echo $lines[array_rand($lines)]; 
        } 
        echo RandomLine($filename);
    ?>
</div>
<div class="home">
    <a href="http://www.jonsnow.net/index.php" id="h1"></a>
    <a href="http://www.jonsnow.net/gallery/" id="h2"></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.home a {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}

div.home img {
    float: top;
    display: inline;
}

div.home {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}

div.qt {
    text-align: "center";
    font-family: "Vivaldi";
    font-size: "44 px";
    color: "#000000";
    position: absolute;
    top: -60%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 62px;
    display: inline;
}

div.home #h1 {
    width:  500px;
    height: 350px;
    display: inline;
    background-image: url('header1.jpg');
}

div.home #h1:hover {
    background-image: url('header1hover.jpg');
}

div.home #h2 {
    width:  500px;
    height: 350px;
    display: inline;
    background-image: url('header2.jpg');
}

div.home #h2:hover {
    background-image: url('header2hover.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Might be easier to visualize if you included the generated HTML instead of the PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
div.qt {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Vivaldi;
    font-size: 44px;
    color: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    top: -60%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 62px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take the quotes off of

```
center
```

in your CSS. And font-size and color for that matter.

Comment: Also, remove quotes from the `font-size` and `color`. Properties with quotes are interpreted differently.

Comment: Oh.. That was simple... Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed another problem with it, on div.home img {} you have float:top; you can't float an element top, you either have Left, Right, None or Inherit